# Broadcom Wireless on Debian doesn't work

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, debian, broadcom

I'm running Debian Linux on a MacBook4,1 with the legendary Broadcom wireless chipset. Before updating the kernel to 3.2.0.1, following [this guide](http://wiki.debian.org/wl) to set up wireless worked like a charm.

However, after updating the kernel, when running `m-a a-i broadcom-sta` the following happens:

[image: module assistant says "Bad luck, the kernel headers for the target kernel version could not be found and you did not specify other valid kernel headers to use."]

A bit of info:

```
user@mac-debian:~$ lspci | grep Broadcom
02:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4321 802.11a/b/g/n (rev 03)

user@mac-debian:~$uname -r
3.2.0-1-amd64
```

Obviously:

```
root@mac-debian:/home/user# iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.
eth0      no wireless extensions.
```

Any ideas to get som wireless up in this?

Comment: Good luck with broadcom-sta, last time I tried to build it there was still some errors in broadcom-sta-source that wouldn't let it build, about a week ago. I was only able to get my wireless working by following this: http://linuxwireless.org/en/users/Drivers/b43

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Kernel headers must be earlier than the kernel you're running.
1) Check the `/usr/src/` directory.

2) If corresponding headers (the same as your kernel version) are there, point the module assistant to them:
`sudo module-assistant --kernel-dir /usr/src/your_kernel_version auto-install broadcom-sta`

3) If not, install the corresponding headers package through apt:
`sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)`

 Then, go back to step 2.

Comment: After installing via Synaptic PM (apt-get didn't work) I get the following error message from module assistant: "Warning, /usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-1-common seems to contain unconfigured kernel source (see manpage for details)!"

Comment: Let's try to see if the kernel-headers are correct. Please, run the `sudo m-a prepare` command and then `sudo m-a a-i broadcom-sta` . If it doesn't work, it seems that we'll need to configure the kernel manually.

Comment: thanks for your answer! As I'm presently in a pretty mission-critical time on the PC, I decided to revert to kernel 2.6.32-5-amd64 - it works. Your answer seems complete, so in the interest of closure: accepted.